# when i start eclipse and run android project, it opens a new emulator every time ,

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Eclipse Android Emulator takes average 7 minutes to launch an activity ,its quite a long time 
Once emulator is Set ,Other projects can be run in same emulator which takes less times.
Sometimes when i start eclipse and run android project, it opens a new emulator every time instead of installing the project in same emulator.

I have searched about this problem,I found the Single good Reason, **Connection refused for the sensor ports is a common problem** I am not sure , This is the real reason

I am using *Eclipse for Windows*,not Mac or Linux and previous activity is properly set before i run the next project

Help me to figure out, what can be the reason behind this problem and how can i make it normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are running Eclipse with the ADT plug in what normally happens is (1) you run you project (2) it asks to to select an android device (3) if no device is available, e.g. a valid emulator, it will ask you to create one.

If Eclipse is asking you to creat a new emulator every time it is likley beacuse either (1) you have not selected the option on the pop up window indicating that you would like to always run the project in a specific listed instance of your emulator (2) there really is no compatable emulator available.

If an emulator is created but not being found (as I suspect is happeneing), you need to refresh your ADT plug in connectino to that emulator. You can do this from within eclipse by going to the devices view (window --> show view --> other --> android --> devices), selecting the downward facing triangle all the way on the right and choosing "reset adb". This will reboot the android device bridge, a.k.a. what connects eclipse to your emulator, and will allow it to recognize that instance again. You should be able to run your project on that emulator from then on.

Comment: Device was already there, and it never asked to add a new device .it just opened it.

Comment: as you predicted emulator is created but not being found. Reset adb totally worked.
When Emulator has some thing in SD card, but can not be loaded , it create problem

Comment: Good to know. I never tried to use the SD card on the emulator, I always tested that with a real device.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid starting emulator automatically by going to

`run` --> `run configuration` --> `target` tab. Then select "**Always prompt to pick device.**" Run the project after this and select a different emulator device.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a solution, but I noticed that clearing the memory on the emulator helped me on a few occasions. Also, I had an issue where I didn't notice the console was stating that my emulator was running on a lower API that the app requested, so it opened the next best emulator instance.